# Using Selenium to select an anchor with specific content

Tags: python, selenium

I have a HTML element as follows:

```
<a class="country" href="/es-co">
    Columbia
</a>
```

How do I select that anchor element based on the content 'Columbia'? I can't use `find_element_by_class_css_selector` because `a.country` represents half a dozen elements. How do I select that element and click it using Silenium with Python (through IE, if that has any bearing)?

As an aside, I could have any number of links with the same text and CSS selectors. How would Silenium differentiate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `find_element_by_class_css_selector`. But you are right, you can't use class names.

The best way is to use `href="/es-co"`, if it's unique.

```
find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='/es-co']")
```

Otherwise you can find by text using XPath

```
find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(text(), 'Columbia')])
```

If you have many links with same locator, then you can index them, either by XPath directly or  the list returned by Selenium.

For example, if you have ten `Columbia`

```
find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(text(), 'Columbia')][10]") # one-based index, one element only
find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[contains(text(), 'Columbia')]")[9] #  find_elements_* gives you zero-base index list
```

Comment: [There is](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_css_selector) a selector by that name.

Comment: @Nanor: Look again please. :) I'm talking about  `find_element_by_class_css_selector` doesn't exist (which you posted), not `find_element_by_css_selector`

Comment: Ahh haha, curse my fat fingers! Seems I've been trying to combine a couple of selectors. Thanks for your help. Your xpath stuff will definitely be useful in the future.

Comment: @Nanor: The reason I didn't give `find_element_by_link_text`, it's because you will meet situation with messy whitespaces. Use CSS/XPath when it's possible. Matching text is bad practice, what if your site supports multi-language in the future? You tests will fail.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `<a>` with clickable text, Selenium provides API like `find_with_link_text` or `find_with_partial_link_text` (API name many be different but you got the idea).

If there are many `<a>` with same `text/css-class`, best bet to locate them is using XPath that is accepted by selenium APIs.

Comment: Perfect! More information here: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text