# Selenium find_element_with_link_text not working

Tags: python, selenium

I have a piece of code as follows

```
<a class="country" href="/es-hn">
    Honduras
</a>
```

and I'm trying to assign to to a variable by doing

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Honduras')
```

However whenever I run it I get the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u"Unable to find element with link text == Honduras"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've seen `link_text` fuzz up when trying to find a link when it's in block formation like this. I think it has something to do with the tabulation:

```
<a class="country" href="/es-hn">
[    ]Honduras
</a>
```

It only seems to work consistently when in line like this:

```
<a class="country" href="/es-hn">Honduras</a>
```

#### Try this:

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.country[href$='es-hn']")
```

Comment: I'm quite fed up with people just keep asking without thinking. In OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22529952/1177636), I gave almost the same answer, but OP just accepted another one (the one wasn't explained clearly enough). Now OP is confused, but came back and asked a new question without even looking back.

Comment: @user1177636 WOW!..... I just read the previous question.  just.. wow.  I gave you an upvote.. good content, and you're absolutely right (minus your xpath suggestion `;)`)

Comment: Well I've went back and selected your answer, @user1177636 because it does indeed work. This does not make this question any less valid. The above code does not work and I'd like to find out why. It should work, it doesn't and I'm trying to find out why. That's why I asked it as a separate question.

Comment: Can also confirm that partial_link_text isn't working for me with a link that has text starting with a line feed character.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with sircapslot, in this case `partial link text` would also work:

```
el = self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Honduras')
```

Answer (score 0):

This may occur when selenium is trying to find the link while your application hasn't rendered it yet. So you need to make it wait until the link appears:

```
browser.implicitly_wait(10) # 10 seconds
el = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Honduras')
```

The `implicitly_wait` call makes the browser poll until the item is on the page and visible to be interacted with.

Comment: I've tried this. I've watched the screen and the link is definitely on screen but it doesn't seem to catch it.